# I'm trying to have a TextView generate a random number every 472 ms, five times. How would I use a loop to do this?

Tags: android

So, I have a TextView that generates a random number. I need that TextView to generate a random number every 472 ms, five times. So I tap the screen and a random number appears then 472 ms later another number appears, and this repeats until five random numbers have been displayed. I know I need to use a loop but what condition would I use to make sure that only five random numbers are generated?

Here's my XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="perform_action"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="75dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="400sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And my Java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void perform_action(View view) {
    Random r = new Random();
    int minNumber = 1;
    int maxNumber = 9;
    int randomNumber = r.nextInt((maxNumber-minNumber)+1)+minNumber;
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setText(String.valueOf(randomNumber));
}
}
```

Comment: what about using a `CountDownTimer` which gives you a tick every x millisecond ? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [rxjava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava)

add these dependencies :

```
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.2'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.0'
```

and then when you click your button :

```
final List< Integer > randomNumbers = new ArrayList<>( );
Observable.intervalRange( 0, 5, 0, 472, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS )
        .map( aLong -> {
            int previous = randomNumbers.size( ) > 0 ? randomNumbers.get(
                    randomNumbers.size( ) - 1 ) : -1;
            int randomNumber = generateRandomNumber();
            while( randomNumber == previous ) generateRandomNumber();
            randomNumbers.add( randomNumber );
            return randomNumber;
        } )
        .observeOn( AndroidSchedulers.mainThread( ) )
        .subscribe(integer -> {
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            tv.setText(String.valueOf(integer));
        } );

private int generateRandomNumber( )
{
    Random r = new Random( );
    int minNumber = 1;
    int maxNumber = 9;
    return r.nextInt( ( maxNumber - minNumber ) + 1 ) + minNumber;
}
```

That's it!

Comment: This works but there seems to be a variation in time period. Some times it displays 5 numbers but other times it displays less than five and the time period is slower. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Are you clicking multiple times from your button before loop is complete? in that case do you want to allow this behaviour (multiple loop at the same time) or not?

Comment: No. I think it's just repeating the same number. Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: Thanks. My "generateRandomNumber" is getting a cannot resolve method error. Did you have an import that I didn't?

Comment: Now it works but sometimes the app doesn't respond to my click/touch.

Comment: It also sometimes only displays one number.

Answer (score 0):

Create a counter to check how many times its touched.

```
int counter=0;
```

create a touch listener .

```
mView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        //paste logic here
        return false;
    }
});
```

The logic will be.

```
if(counter<=5){
perform_action();
counter++;
}
```